# Cargo.toml reports problem: "could not compile `rand`"

Tags: rust

When following the official guess game chapter, after adding `rand` as dependency and running `cargo build`, the `Cargo.toml` file start to display red lines with the problem: "could not compile `rand`". However, I can still run the program without any issues...

fyi. using vs code and rust extension.

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Try to restart the extension host (ctrl+shift+p) or use the Rust analyzer instead.

Comment: You should use the `rust-analyzer` extension. Also, when VS Code causes trouble, it's often enough to restart it.

Comment: @JakubDóka Yeah I've restarted VS Code several times but can't fix it. Will take a look at Rust Analyzer. Thx.